# Disable su and sudo access for users

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, sudo, ssh-agent

I have created a couple of users who use their SSH Keys to log in on a server.

I don't want any user to have root access, i.e, no user should be able to do `sudo su` or `su - another user`.

When I check the user, I can see only these

```
id user
uid=1001(user) gid=1001(user) groups=1001(user)
```

I have checked across the internet, I found how to disable `sudo` access for users with a password but I want to disable it for users who are using their SSH keys to log in?

I want to disable `sudo` and `su` access for user that log in using SSH. How will I do it?

Edit 01:

I have done the following;

```
sudo deluser user sudo

/usr/sbin/deluser: The user is not a member of group `sudo'.
```

and

```
sudo gpasswd -d user sudo

Removing the user from group sudo
gpasswd: the user is not a member of 'sudo'
```

After that, I checked

```
sudo -l -U user

User  may run the following commands on the server:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

User is still able to run `sudo su` and get root access.

EDIT 02:

@Panki, The snippet

```
visudo

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL: ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Well, you forgot to mention in your question that your `/etc/sudoers` file allows _anybody_ without a password to run every command as `root`. This is a very bad idea for obvious reasons. You should edit the file (use `visudo` for this) and restore a sane state.

Comment: `(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` comes from somewhere. If it's not directly in the `sudoers` file then maybe the file contains `#include` or `#includedir` (they are *not* comments). Learn what they do (see `man 5 sudoers`), locate files/directories they point to and investigate. If you need to change anything, use `visudo -f`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not create a user using SSH keys. The user logs in to the machine using SSH keys after creation.

For `sudo`, there is no difference in how the user authenticates.

To prevent users from using `sudo`, remove them from the group `sudo`. To prevent them from using `su`, don't tell them the root password.

Comment: Thanks, @Panki, I have also done the following which I have added in the edit.

User access only using SSH, not password